# Sending A Transaction Async | Cannot Resolve Method 'executeTransactionAsync'

Tags: java, android, realm, ethereum, web3-java

I am attemping to send a transaction to the Ethereum blockchain using the Web3j library, I get an error that I must send it with Async. When I send it with Async I get an error that the function does not exist.
I am using Android Studio, Java, and the Web3j library.

When calling the `executeTransactionAsync` method, part of `web3.abi.datatypes.Function`, I get an error saying the method can not be found. I figured out this means that the method `executeTransactionAsync` does not exist in the Web3j library. However, the Web3j documentation says to use that method. I am using the latest version of Web3j which is 3.1.1.

If I remove the Async so the method is `executeTransaction`, I get an error that the Transaction needs to be sent through Async.

Is there a way I could send this transaction with Realm or something else? Or maybe I am using Web3j wrong and I need to use it another way?

---

The code sending the transaction:

```
public TransactionReceipt approve() throws IOException, TransactionException {
    Function function = new Function("approve", Arrays.<Type>asList(), Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeTransactionAsync (function);
}
```

---

[Web3j API](https://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transactions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an `executeTransaction` wrapped in a `RemoteCall`.

```
Function function = new Function(...);
RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> remoteCall = new RemoteCall(() -> {
  //call to executeTransaction
});
TransactionReceipt receipt = remoteCall.send();
```

You can make life easier for yourself by using web3j's code generation tools which creates simple wrappers for your smart contract. See [this section](https://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/smart_contracts.html#solidity-smart-contract-wrappers) of the web3j documentation on how to generate your code. The generated class handles the remote calls (and local calls for `constant` functions). Your client code becomes something like:

```
Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService());
Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(<YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY>);
SimpleContract contract = SimpleContract.load(<CONTRACT_ADDRESS>, web3j, credentials, BigInteger.valueOf(<GAS_PRICE>), BigInteger.valueOf(<GAS_LIMIT));
RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> remoteCall = contract.setValue(BigInteger.valueOf(5)); // Call to smart contract setValue(5)
TransactionReceipt receipt = remoteCall.send();
```

**Edit to add code generation example**

```
$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.Windows.msvc

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

$ solc contracts/SimpleContract.sol --bin --abi --optimize -o build/

$ web3j.bat solidity generate build/SimpleContract.bin build/SimpleContract.abi -o ./src -p mypackage

              _      _____ _     _
             | |    |____ (_)   (_)
__      _____| |__      / /_     _   ___
\ \ /\ / / _ \ '_ \     \ \ |   | | / _ \
 \ V  V /  __/ |_) |.___/ / | _ | || (_) |
  \_/\_/ \___|_.__/ \____/| |(_)|_| \___/
                         _/ |
                        |__/

Generating mypackage.SimpleContract ... File written to .\src
```

Note - I'm running on Windows with Cygwin. Hence, the `web3j.bat` usage.

Comment: I am currently using infura. Is this required?

Comment: I also tried the automatic generator and the code had tons of errors.

Comment: I am getting the error Lamda expressions are not supported at this level.

Comment: The error is on the line `return executeTransaction(function);`

Comment: I added an example of using solc + web3j for wrapper generation. To connect to Infura, replace the default `HttpService` with the Infura URL + your API key (see https://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/infura.html). Also, make sure you're on Java 8+ for lambda support. If you can't use lambdas in your project, you may have to edit the generated code to rewrite the lambdas (should be pretty easy).

Comment: I am using android studio. I did it a different way. I want you to get the correct answer for your time so i will edit your answer.

Comment: I will just accept it and change the question to java